# Not able to execute jquery code in puppeteer

Tags: jquery, puppeteer

I need to click an anchor tag with in a table.
This anchor tag is located as first element in the last td of a tr.

I am able to do using jQuery but I'm facing issues when I try to execute the same with Puppeteer can you please help me on the same.

my jQuery code is

```
  $('table tr td.uname').each(function(el){

    var name  = $(this).text();

   if($.trim(name) == 'testmyself111'){
     $(this).parent().find(':last-child>a')[0].click();
   }
  });
```

This is what I'm trying to do but not able to execute

```
      await page.addScriptTag({
        url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'
     });
      let tr = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let results;
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td.uname');
       
             items.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.innerText == 'TESTMYSELF111') {
                results = item.parentElement;
            }
       
        });
        return results;
    });
    const anchor = await page.evaluate((tr) => {
        // get the body anchor tag 
        const atag= $(tr).parent().find(':last-child>a')[0];
        return atag;
    }, tr);
    console.log(anchor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return `Node` objects from the page back to your NodeJS script. You will need to do one of the following:

1. Evaluate all of your on-page scripts within the same `evaluate` call.
2. Use the puppeteer [`$`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.4.0&show=api-pageselector), [`$$`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.4.0&show=api-pageselector-1), [`$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.4.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) or [`$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.4.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) functions to manipulate the nodes without executing your script within the browser's `Execution Context`.
3. Return a serializable reference to the nodes (e.g. a fully qualified selector or other manually generated node address that you can pass into the next `evaluate` call.